# Как обработать несколько массивов и присвоить им новое значение

Tags: php

Подскажите синтаксис

```
function modify(&$type_arr, &$local_arr, &$locType, &$park_arr, &$arr_com, $vars) {
    foreach ($vars as &$v) {
        $v = asort($v);
    }
}

modify($vars);

$vars = [$type_arr, $local_arr, $locType, $park_arr, $arr_com];
```

Comment: Подсказать синтаксис чего?

Comment: то, что я привел в примере, этот код у меня не работает. Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: Как он должен работать и какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: я хочу отсортировать несколько массивов. Можно перописать каждый asort($type_arr) и т.д, но как это сделать это в функции например ?

Comment: 1) вы вызываете функцию раньше, чем создаёте массив
2) передавайте по ссылке один массив, а не кучу и общий
3) если работаете с ссылками то не нужно ничего переприсваивать

Comment: Да Роман, спасибо, я вчера поправил еще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function methodSort(&$var)
{
    foreach ($var as &$v) {
        asort($v);
    }
}

$type_arr = ["d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple"];
$type_arr2 = ["d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple"];

$vars = [$type_arr, $type_arr2];
methodSort($vars);

var_dump($vars);
```

Comment: Спасибо Олег, все так. Я хотел знать применение кода к множеству переменных или массивов. Это то, что нужно !

Comment: Сделайте ответ правильным пожалуйста и можете поставить что он полезен)